# How to using Dapper to extract data from column dynamically altered table

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, dynamic-programming, dapper

I am facing an issue due to client's new requirement. I have a table called `Tasks` and a table named `Codes`.

`Tasks` table:

| ID | Taskname |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2D |
| 2 | 3D |

`Codes` table

| ID | Codename | For2D | For3D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2D | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 3D | 0 | 1 |

Now user is able to click button in frontend to add an new entry in Task table. Correspondingly a new column should also be added in the `Codes` table. For example:
New `Tasks` table:

| ID | Taskname |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2D |
| 2 | 3D |
| 3 | 4D |

New `Codes` table

| ID | Codename | For2D | For3D | For4D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2D | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 2 | 3D | 0 | 1 | 1 |

For adding column part I can handle with **Dapper**. But how could I write the query and use **Dapper** to extract data from table and send to frontend? Because I have no idea how many new rows user will add in the `Tasks` table.

Currently I has a class

```
public class DqcDto
{
    public string? DqcCode { get; set; }
    public string? DqcDescription { get; set; }
    public string Project { get; set; }
    public bool? IsFor3D { get; set; }
    public bool? IsFor2D { get; set; }
}
```

But this won't be used when user add new columns.

Comment: First impression is that "Codes" is a "lookup" for "Tasks"; and the general approach is "in the wrong order". Better naming would help an outside observer in figuring out what the "data model" should look like.

Comment: Generally we want our tables to grow vertically, not horizontally. Without more context is difficult to say how you could solve it.

Comment: @PalleDue I notice that also. I have change my solution to create table for each task and each table contains the code column. 
Thank you for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

You could try below code to query database and get dynamic result using dapper:

```
using Dapper;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Dynamic;
using System.Text.Json;


var connectionString = "ConnectionString";
var query = "SELECT * FROM Codes";

using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    var dynamicResults = connection.Query<dynamic>(query).ToList();
    foreach (var row in dynamicResults)
    {
        foreach (var property in (IDictionary<string, object>)row)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{property.Key}: {property.Value}");
        }
    }
    
    var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(dynamicResults);
Console.WriteLine(json);// send `json` to the frontend

}
```

This code will help queries all columns from the `Codes` table and iterates over each row, treating it as a dynamic object.

Comment: I am sure this is a useful answer, although I changed my solution to create table for each task and each table contains code column

Comment: @AoLiGei glad to hear that you found the solution. i would like to request you to post your solution as an answer and mark so that it can help other user in future.